# PHP session doesn't pass through files

Tags: php, session, uploadify

I am using Uploadify for my script.

The main page:

```
<?php

session_start();

var_dump($_SESSION);
$uploaded_files = $_SESSION['uploaded_files'];

?>

//Uploadify, HTML forms and more (not related, No PHP in this section)
```

uploadify.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once('includes/functions.php');

// Define a destination
$targetFolder = 'uploads/temp'; // Relative to the root

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
    $file_hash = GenRndStr(20) . '.' . $fileParts['extension'];
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $file_hash;

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array(); // File extensions

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
    $_SESSION['uploaded_files'][] = $file_hash;
    echo '1';
}

?>
```

I'm sure it gets to the `$_SESSION['uploaded_files'][] = $file_hash;` part, since the actual file is uploaded to the directory. My problem is that the `var_dump` of `$_SESSION['uploaded_files']` returns null.

The files are in the same directory level.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the output of the upper `var_dump`? What is the `var_dump` of `$SESSION` in the second file after the last `}`? What is the actual process? You upload files via uploadify.php, store the hashes in the session and cannot access them in, say, main.php which is displayed afterwards? Also, the output of `echo session_id();` after `session_start();` might give you a hint whether you are even accessing the same session either times.

Comment: First dump gives null, second gives the correct list

Comment: I now see that the pages generate different session's id. How is that possible? Thanks for pointing that out, I have been sitting for hours trying to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem is that Uploadify's flash version is treated as a different client for the server, therefore the server creates a new session id for it.

I followed this topic: http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/43
Hope it'll help others.